# Change global variable value jQuery

Tags: jquery

Trying to change value on scrolling in jQuery.

```
var a= 10;
$(window).scroll(function() {
  a= $(this).scrollTop();
});

console.log(a);
```

Here is fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jpb2rfxa/

Still console shows 10. How to change the value?

Comment: print the `a` in your console directly after scrolling your page.

Comment: inside scroll function it works but i need the scroll value outsite function

Comment: It WILL have changed. You output the value of a directly after you set in. Thats why its 10. If you would set a Timeout and scroll in this time, it will have changed. Same goes for every function which will use this global value. `a` WILL have the new value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do understand what you want, but I don't understand why you don't understand what the code does.

```
var a = 10;
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var a = $(this).scrollTop();
  console.log(a);
});
```

This code will change the value of a on each scroll, *and* output that value on each scroll event. The console.log will thus happen on each scroll.

```
var a = 10;
$(window).scroll(function() {
  a = $(this).scrollTop();
});

console.log(a);
```

In this code, a will still change on each scroll. However, console.log will only be called once, namely the very first time the file is read - without any scrolling taking place. That's because .scroll is an event handler that only fires when an event takes place (in this case the scrolling). So first the console.log will take place (just once) and because the user hasn't scrolled yet, the value will be 10. If a user then scrolls, the value will change but console.log isn't called again so you don't see the new value in console (even though a *has* changed!).

I assume that you want to use the value of `a` in a function every time it changes, but if so this is not the way to do it. You then need to call that function inside the scroll event because you want to call the function with a new value each time.

```
var a = 10;
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var a = $(this).scrollTop();
  logging(a);
});

function logging(val) {
  console.log(val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javscript or jquery the scope of variables is functional  ..i.e the variable 'a' which you have in your window.scroll function is getting updated but it does that when the user actually scrolls the element which you have attached it to. And you are printing to log the same original value.

If you move your console.log inside the scroll function you might see the result you expect .. and it will print in console when you perform a scroll event.

```
var a= 10;
$(window).scroll(function() {
a= $(this).scrollTop();
console.log(a);
});
```

Comment: I need the value outside of the scroll function.

Comment: Yes you will be able to acess the value outside the scroll function. But the value of variable a wont change unless you perform a scroll on tag you have attached it to.

Comment: Needed the changed value not previous assigned value

Comment: ok so try this 

var a= 10;
a= $(this).scrollTop();
console.log(a);

Just make sure you refer the right element in ...... $(this) .....**window** i guess